# FindWindow returns zero in MASM32 program even if the window exists

Tags: winapi, assembly, x86, masm, masm32

I'm trying to write a program in assembly and one of the first things that I need is the handle of the main window of a specific process. I've been trying to get it using FindWindow, but no luck so far; FindWindow apparently keeps returning zero. Can anyone point out what am I missing here? Thanks.

```
.486
.model flat, stdcall
option casemap :none
include \masm32\include\user32.inc
include \masm32\include\kernel32.inc
includelib \masm32\lib\user32.lib
includelib \masm32\lib\kernel32.lib

.data
    NtpTitle    db  "Untitled - Notepad",0
    MsgNoNtp    db  "Notepad not found.",0
    MsgNtp      db  "Found Notepad.",0
    NullString  db  0
    hWndNtp     dd  0

.code
start:
    invoke FindWindow, offset NullString, offset NtpTitle
    mov hWndNtp, eax
    jz noNotepad
    invoke MessageBox, 0, offset MsgNtp, 0, 40h
    invoke ExitProcess, 0

noNotepad:
    invoke MessageBox, 0, offset MsgNoNtp, 0, 10h
    invoke ExitProcess, 1

end start
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should set `lpClassName` to NULL, not the address to an empty string.

```
invoke FindWindow, 0, offset NtpTitle
```

You are not testing the return value of `FindWindow`; mov does not modify flags.

```
test eax,eax
jz noNotepad
```

Comment: Thanks. However, I've tried NULL and 0 already and neither seemed to work. Even making both arguments `0` didn't make FindWindow return any windows. If this is the problem, it isn't the only one :\

Comment: Does `FindWindow` compile into `FindWindowA` or `FindWindowW`? If W, the string won't match the window title.

Comment: Just re-checked, it compiles to `FindWindowA`.

Comment: You're not checking the return value, I've expanded my answer.